# Converting Linear PCM file to M4A file in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation

Using built-in iOS libraries, how can I convert a linear PCM file recorded using AVAudioRecorder to m4a. I know I can record it originally in that format, but I need it in linear PCM first. 
I'm semi-familiar with ExtAudioFile but I can't quite get it to do what I want.
Any ideas?

Best,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at this sample project, should do what you want out of the box, you just need to modify it to fit your needs. [Sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html). Another way you can do it is using AVFoundation, with AVAssetWriter/AVAssetReader, check out [this link](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/) for more info

Comment: Indeed, I've been looking at AVAssetWriter/Reader but i'm looking for an explanation of how these work as there's not much I can find online.

Comment: @MaxWoolf check out the link i posted for info on that

Comment: The sample is nice, but it doesn't output to compressed formats (AVAssetWriter). For that it seems that we need to use the ExtAudio converter example.

Comment: @JoseAraujo I believe it should suport output to compressed, you just need to uncompress first..

Comment: @Daniel, I actually took tried the project. Changed it to take a source PCM Linear file, and tried to convert to IMA. Unfortunately I lost the error message but it said specifically that the class didn't support compressed output formats. Thanks. If you know that it should work I am probably willing to give it another try (having issues with the alternative).

Comment: Daniel, I tried. I set the AVFormatIDKey = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC, when executing `output = [AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput assetReaderAudioMixOutputWithAudioTracks:input.tracks audioSettings:outputSettings];` the program crashes with exception message "AVAsssetReaderOutput does not currently support compressed output". Note that I am using SDK5. I do not think this is possible in this version.